# Cognos reporting on Hive datasource is very slow?

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hive, db2, cognos

I am new to Cognos and trying to create reports on top of Hadoop using Hive JDBC Driver. I'm able to connect to Hive through JDBC and can able to generate reports, but here the report runs very slow. I did the same job while connecting with DB2 and the data is same as in Hadoop. Reports ran very quickly when compared to reports on top of Hive. I'm using same data-sets in both Hadoop and DB2, but can't figure out why reports on top of Hadoop are very slow. I installed Hadoop in pseudo distributed mode and connected through JDBC.

I installed following versions of software's which I used,

- IBM Cognos 10.2.1 with fix pack 11,
- Apache Hadoop 2.7.2,
- Apache Hive 0.12.

Both are installed in different systems, Cognos on top of Windows 7 and Hadoop on top of Red-Hat.

Can any one tell me where I might be wrong in setting up of Cognos or Hadoop. Is there any way to speed up the report running time in Cognos on top of Hadoop.

Comment: Hive is generally going to be slower than an RDBMS.  Have you tested your query directly in Hive?

Comment: Is there any way to increase the speed because the reports are running very slow, for a simple report only it takes 2 to 3 mins of time

Answer (score 1):

When you say you installed Hadoop in pseudo distributed mode are you saying you are only running it on a single server?  If so, it's never going to be as fast as DB2.  Hadoop and Hive are designed to run on a cluster and scale.  Get 3 or 4 servers running in a cluster and you should find that you can start to see some impressive query speeds over large datasets.

Check that you have allowed the Cognos Query Service to access more than the default amount of memory for it's Java Heap (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21587457)  I currently run an initial size of 8Gb and max of 12Gb, but still manage to blow this occasionally.

Next issue you will run into is that Cognos doesn't know Hive SQL specifics (or Impala which is what I am using).  This means that any non-basic query is going to be converted to a select  from  and maybe a group by.  The big missing piece will be a where clause, which will mean that Cognos is going to try to suck in all the data from the Hive table and then do the filtering in Cognos rather than pass that off to Hive where it belongs.  Cognos knows how to write DB2 SQL and all the specifics so it can pass that workload through.

The more complex the query, or any platform specific functions etc will generally not get passed to Hive (date functions, analytic functions etc), so try to structure your data and queries so they are required in filters.

Use the Hive query logs to monitor the queries that Cognos is running.  Also try things like add fields to the query and then drag that field to the filter rather than direct from the model into the filter.  I have found this can help in getting Cognos to include the filter in a where clause.

The other option is to use passthrough SQL queries in Report Studio and just write it all in Hive's SQL.  I have just done this for a set of dashboards which required a stack of top 5's from a fact table with 5 million rows. For 5 rows Cognos was extracting all 5 million rows and then ranking them within Cognos.  Do this a number of times and all of a sudden Cognos is going to struggle.  With a passthrough query I could use the Impala Rank() function and only get 5 rows, much much faster, and faster than what DB2 would do seeing I am running on a proper (but small) cluster.

Another consideration with Hive is whether you are using Hive on Map Reduce or Hive on TEZ.  From what a colleague has found, Hive on TEZ is much faster at the type of queries Cognos runs than Hive on Map Reduce.